# How to reuse code in microservices architecture

Tags: java, architecture, microservices

I have 2 services (service1 and service2),and both services are using the same data model "studentModel",I'm wondering how to share the studentModel between the two services.

1.Build a studentModel.jar , and all the services refer to this jar

2.Copy & Paste code

Please help me how to reuse code in microservices architecture.

Comment: build a jar and add it as dependency to your service projects

Comment: You have to treat any code dependency like you would treat an external dependency, e.g. an open source component from github. That means you have to version the components correctly and move up versions like you would with an external dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend going even further. From my experience, the best approach would be the following:

1. to build a separate module with all models for the microservice
2. to build a separate client library (module) for the microservice

Following this approach, you can release a new client library each time you change your micro-service - it will be easy to maintain and manage.

In addition, it will help you to save a lot of time when your system grows. Just imagine, you're going to use your core service (e.g. user service or profile service) as a dependency for all other services. Copy-paste is definitely not an option in this case.

**Update.** Currently, we have such things as OpenAPI and GraphQL in our toolsets. It's enough to design a good schema for the supplier service and simply use code generation tools for consumers.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to microservices, its ok to keep duplicated files because you might end up with a distributed monolith. Remember the Bounded Context from DDD and use your thought process. No shared library means no coupling.

But again the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) says you should not have duplicate, but to what extent?

One failure in one Library should not cause all your microservices to fail using that library, then the whole purpose of microservice is of no use.

There are tools to shared code among microservices, you can have a look into **https://bitsrc.io/**

All these are my thought, there must be some better way.

Comment: Yes,Coupling and DRY are not compatible in microservices architecture.

Comment: I think DRY and Decoupling are perfectly compatible. In a Microservice environment each service should have a purpose in the system, so the module might not be a duplication as it can diverge in the future. The reason to use the same jar with the same model is only connected to the fact they have just one reason to change. If they have more, than it's not a duplication.

Comment: See my comment on the OPs question. Just treat the dependency like an external one with correct versioning. Duplicating files will run you quickly into update hell.

Comment: IF you implement your common library with a version, then you won't violate the no coupling of MS.

Answer (score 0):

For better version control, I would recommend you to build a jar and add it as a dependency on your microservices. Alternatively, you can also explore git sub modules by putting duplicate codes in sub modules and utilizing it in your respective microservice module.